# Python string.find() giving error "slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method"

Tags: python

I am trying to do a simple sub string matching in Python and although I remember last night it was working fine, but since morning this piece of code is giving the following error. It seems to be a known error, can anyone suggest why is it happening?

```
if string.find(row[1],drug) != -1:
    print "abstract id =  ", row[0],"Drug found=", drug
```

error :

```
File "./substring.py", line 31, in <module>
    if string.find(row[1],drug) != -1:
TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method
```

Here `row[1]` and `drug` both are simple strings.

Comment: Does this include `import string` to use the `string` package?  Or do you have a string-valued variable named `string`?  What is `string` in your example?

Comment: I have used 'import string' and string is not a variable. although I changed it to row[1].find(drug) and it worked but I am still curious how the above code was working last night.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of `string.find(row[1], drug)`, try `row[1].find(drug)`.  The `.find()` method will give you the index of the first occurrence of the string.

Answer (score 8):

What is `string`?

This would work if it were the module `string`.

If it is a string object instead (the error suggests that this is the case), then the second argument is the position at which it should start searching. The position must be an integer or `None` or an object with `__index__` method. `drug` is a string so you get an error.

What you probably wanted is:

```
if row[1].find(drug) != -1:
```

but it's better to use `in` for simple substring checks:

```
if drug in row[1]:
```